# Customise Internet Browser path in Lotus Notes

Tags: browser, lotus-notes

Using Lotus Notes 8.5.2. If I select `Office` in the lower right status bar  (this might be `Online` if you are working from home) then `Edit Current...` several useful options can be configured. Alternatively, choose `File - Preferences - Location Preferences...`

[image: Edit Notes profile]

[image: Internet Browser settings]

The path to the internet browser is set correctly as:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

but I need to set it to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-infobars
```

This is to disable popup information bars in Chrome. There does not appear to be any way to edit the `path` setting manually. When I browse using the little button on the left, only `chrome.exe` can be selected. Selecting `chrome.exe` and then typing in `--disable-infobars` results in Lotus Notes not being able to launch hyperlinks when I click one in an email.

Is there any way to manually edit this setting (possibly by editing an INI file or registry entry)?

Comment: Are you able to set the path to a **batch file** containing `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-infobars`?

Comment: An excellent suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work. I created a .bat file in the same location as chrome.exe. Inside, I put various calls (such as straight calling, `call` and `start`) to chrome.exe. While this works if I double-click them in Explorer, absolutely nothing happens in Lotus Notes. I even changed the contents of the batch file to `pause` in case it was popping in and out of existence too quick to see...nothing! Perhaps I need to arrange for a call to `cmd.exe %1` where the `%1` points to my secondary batch file?

Comment: It's worth a try ;)

Comment: Irk, struggling here! Lotus Notes (unhelpfully) only lets me select the file itself, but does not allow me to type parameters (as for a normal shortcut). This is the original problem, so the `cmd.exe %1` idea seems to be a non-starter. Suspect that internally Notes is using `ShellExecute` or similar and it cannot handle command-line parameters other than its' own.

Comment: You can build a .bat file and then use one of the various bat-to-exe converters that are out there.  I can't vouch for any one of these, so I'm just linking to the search results.  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bat%20to%20exe